# Is there any way to detect body parts from Vuforia?

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore, easyar

We are going to build an AR(Augmented Reality) application based on Vuforia framework which is for detecting the human's body parts and adding some object onto them.

Is there any way to detect Human's body parts like Face, Neck and Hand's finger using  Vuforia or any other framework such as ARCore, EasyAR?

Comment: Did you get any success on this part. Please guide how you would achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check out TensorFlow PoseNet (pose estimation model): https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview